# Show file and directory permissons from umask value

Tags: linux, command

I have homeword about use umask value to make default file and directory permissons, but I got a problem in the following:

If I have umask = 0541

- 0666 - 0541 = 0125, File permisson: `---x-w-r-x`
- 0777 - 0541 = 0236, Directory permisson: `d-w--wxrw-`

But the actual result on linux terminal:

- `d-w--wxrw` for the directory
- `--w--w-rw-` for the file
  Please explain to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that umask's are not a subtraction, but a logical AND operation based on the umask.

Think of permissions in binary:

So a permission of 0666 would be

```
110 110 110
```

Now a umask of 0541 would be

```
101 100 001
```

To calculate the results we negate the umask:

```
010 011 110
```

and then AND that with the permission.

So

```
110 110 110  AND
010 011 110
=== === ===
010 010 110
```

And that maps to  -w- -w- rw-

Comment: thanks you so much @Stephen ^^!, you saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider it like this, if you have default permissions 666 means that you have only `r+w` for user, group and others, and by umask `541` you want to remove permissions r+x,r,x.

For user:

```
By default you can read+write and by umask you want to remove read+executable 
permissions, but it will never happen because initially file has no executable 
permissions. So only read permission will be removed.
```

For group:

```
read permission will removed
```

For others:

```
There is no executable permission in the file, so there will be no change.
```

Same concept applies for directories.

Comment: thanks for your answer ^^, I found a trick and I think it's right:

Comment: Please add it as answer, if it solves your problem.

Comment: default file=0666 => -rw-rw-rw-
here Umask = 0541 => -r-xr----x
substract them    => --w--w-rw- for the file

Comment: I was checked any value and it's always return a true value